# Is there any even function that occurs in the case of deleting the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keychain

The iPhone app i developed save user data (id, pw) to keychain of iOS by using open source SFHFKeychainUtils

Problem is that the id,pw data still remains intact upon deleting the app,

which cause trouble when reinstalling the app.

Would it be possible to delete the id, pw in the keychaing along with the app?

Is there any even function that occurs in the case of deleting the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your app does not get notified of its deletion. AFAIK, the OS keeps the keychain data for some time (a few days or so) and then deletes it automatically.